# how to resolve A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction in android studio

Tags: android, error-handling, metadata

I have just started a new android studio app and and tried to run but it is giving the following error

```
    Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: 
    A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
```

Here is the build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.littleapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.littleapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.3")

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.1"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.5.1"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.5.1"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.1"
}
```

and this is build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.2.0'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

I have updated all the dependencies and tried `Invalidate and Restart` but nothing seems to be working so far. I don't know why it is giving this error. How changes do I need to make to remove this error?